# How can an object ,moing on surface of Mobius ,be changed from left-handed to right handed without moving it in 3 dimension, as Mobius claims?

Tags: topology, topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

While Mobius claim that the object on it's surface moves in two dimension i.e. " on the surface" but if you could see, the object is actually  moving in 3 dimension because the surface is curved which can only be done in 3 dimension and thus in real there is a 2 dimension object moving along a path in 3 dimension.

Comment: Do you have a link to the passage you're quoting from, or could you be more specific about which particular surface you're talking about?

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking. Please explain how the handedness has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a 2D *Euclidean* space but if you are on the surface of a Möbius strip you can get anywhere else on the surface by moving in two directions along the surface (you might call these forward/backwards and left/right).